# Barrier option Greeks using AD

Tags: programming, monte-carlo, greeks, barrier

I am trying to price a Down-and-Out Barrier option using Monte Carlo and get the Greeks using autodiff as provided by PyTorch. However, comparing the output to bumping, I get vastly different values for the Greeks, and have verified this by bumping using QuantLib also. The price is correct and agrees with QL. This is my code:

```
import torch
import time

torch.set_default_dtype(torch.double)
torch.set_default_device('cpu')
torch.manual_seed(1234)


def simulate_barrier(spot, strike, barrier, vol, rate, expiry, numPaths: int, numSteps: int, normals):
    dt = expiry / numSteps
    times = torch.linspace(start=0., end=expiry, steps=numSteps+1)

    W = torch.concatenate([torch.zeros(numPaths, 1), torch.cumsum(normals, dim=1)], dim=1)
    gbm = spot * torch.exp((rate - vol**2/2)*times + vol*torch.sqrt(dt)*W)

    # (Paul Glasserman.1997. A Continuity correction for Discrete Barrier Options)
    alive = torch.all(gbm > (barrier + (barrier*0.5826 * vol * torch.sqrt(dt))), dim=1)
    payoffs = torch.where(alive, torch.max(gbm[:, -1] - strike, torch.tensor(0.)), torch.tensor(0.))
    return payoffs.mean() * torch.exp(-rate*expiry)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spot = torch.tensor(100., requires_grad=True)
    strike = torch.tensor(100., requires_grad=True)
    rfr = torch.tensor(0.01, requires_grad=True)
    vol = torch.tensor(0.2, requires_grad=True)
    barrier = torch.tensor(90.)
    expiry = torch.tensor(1., requires_grad=True)

    numPaths = 100000
    numSteps = 252
    print(f"Paths:      {numPaths}")
    print(f"Time steps: {numSteps}")

    normals = torch.randn((numPaths, numSteps))

    delta1 = simulate_barrier(spot+1, strike, barrier, vol, rfr, expiry, numPaths, numSteps, normals)
    delta2 = simulate_barrier(spot-1, strike, barrier, vol, rfr, expiry, numPaths, numSteps, normals)

    theta1 = simulate_barrier(spot, strike, barrier, vol, rfr, expiry+0.01, numPaths, numSteps, normals)
    theta2 = simulate_barrier(spot, strike, barrier, vol, rfr, expiry-0.01, numPaths, numSteps, normals)
    
    rho1 = simulate_barrier(spot, strike, barrier, vol, rfr+0.001, expiry, numPaths, numSteps, normals)
    rho2 = simulate_barrier(spot, strike, barrier, vol, rfr-0.001, expiry, numPaths, numSteps, normals)
    
    vega1 = simulate_barrier(spot, strike, barrier, vol+0.01, rfr, expiry, numPaths, numSteps, normals)
    vega2 = simulate_barrier(spot, strike, barrier, vol-0.01, rfr, expiry, numPaths, numSteps, normals)
    
    start = time.time()
    price = simulate_barrier(spot, strike, barrier, vol, rfr, expiry, numPaths, numSteps, normals)
    price.backward()
    end = time.time()

    print(f"\nPrice: {price.item():.2f}")
    print(f"Delta: {spot.grad.item():.4f}")
    print(f"Bump Delta: {(delta1-delta2)/2:.4f}")
    print(f"Theta: {expiry.grad.item():.4f}")
    print(f"Bump Theta: {(theta1-theta2)/0.02:.4f}")
    print(f"Rho:   {rfr.grad.item():.4f}")
    print(f"Bump Rho: {(rho1-rho2)/0.002:.4f}")
    print(f"Vega:  {vol.grad.item():.4f}")
    print(f"Bump Vega: {(vega1-vega2)/0.02:.4f}")
    print(f"\nExecution time: {(end-start):.4f} seconds")
```

With the output:

```
Paths:      100000
Time steps: 252

Price: 6.89
Delta: 0.4027
Bump Delta: 0.7187
Theta: 4.0707
Bump Theta: 1.9855
Rho:   33.3845
Bump Rho: 42.1327
Vega:  33.3415
Bump Vega: 15.3068

Execution time: 0.8077 seconds
```

I cannot seem to find the issue here, and cannot tell whether it is to do with the nature of the Barrier option and difficulties in simulating it or a mistake in my reasoning.

Any thoughts/advice/comparison would be appreciated. Thanks!